# Python given dict of old index: new index move multiple elements in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

In Python 3 what would be the best way to move multiple potentially non-contiguous elements to new potentially non-contiguous indexes given a `dict` of `{old index: new index, old index: new index, old index: new index}`

**Important Note**: the `dict` may not contain all the new positions of elements, this is why the examples below the first example do not work

Edit: Sorry I forgot to mention that you don't have to worry about checking all the indexes in `new_idxs` are valid and within the bounds of `seq`. The keys of `new_idxs` are also already in sorted order

```py
from typing import Any


def move_elements(
    seq: list[Any],
    new_idxs: dict,
) -> list[Any]:
    new = []
    idx = 0
    done = set()
    while len(new) < len(seq):
        if idx in new_idxs and idx not in done:
            new.append(seq[new_idxs[idx]])
            done.add(idx)
        elif idx not in done:
            new.append(seq[idx])
            idx += 1
        else:
            idx += 1
    return new


# works
new_idxs = {0: 1, 1: 0}
seq = [0, 1]
seq = move_elements(seq, new_idxs)
print ("\nexpected:", [1, 0])
print ("actual  :", seq)
# expected output
# [1, 0]

# doesn't work
new_idxs = {3: 0, 5: 1}
seq = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
seq = move_elements(seq, new_idxs)
print ("\nexpected:", [3, 5, 0, 1, 2, 4, 6, 7])
print ("actual  :", seq)
# expected output
# [3, 5, 0, 1, 2, 4, 6, 7]

# doesn't work
new_idxs = {3: 6, 5: 7}
seq = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
seq = move_elements(seq, new_idxs)
print ("\nexpected:", [0, 1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 3, 5])
print ("actual  :", seq)
# expected output
# [0, 1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 3, 5]

new_idxs = {3: 1, 7: 4}
seq = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
seq = move_elements(seq, new_idxs)
print ("\nexpected:", [0, 3, 1, 2, 7, 4, 5, 6])
print ("actual  :", seq)
# expected output
# [0, 3, 1, 2, 7, 4, 5, 6]

new_idxs = {0: 3, 3: 1, 7: 4}
seq = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
seq = move_elements(seq, new_idxs)
print ("\nexpected:", [1, 3, 2, 0, 7, 4, 5, 6])
print ("actual  :", seq)
# expected output
# [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
# [1, 3, 2, 0, 7, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: This isn't a swap. What's supposed to happen to the clobbered elements? For example: what's the expected output for `new_idxs={3:1, 7:4}`?

Comment: For each index pair in the dict, swap the list elements at those indexes.  What is the difficulty?

Comment: @MichaelRuth Sorry, example updated `# [0, 3, 1, 2, 7, 4, 5, 6]`

Comment: I can see the physical sense of what you're trying to do. Sure it's fine for a small `seq` with two mapped indexes, but I'm thinking about the case where `seq` is large and `new_idxs` is such that there's a lot of segmentation in the new `seq`. I messed around with this a bit and I think any implementation is going to be very fragile, even before considering input validation.

Comment: @KellyBundy I put it there in case others would need access to such a thing ._. creating it outside the function in this case is a leftover from my program though sorry for the confusion I will change that

Comment: Doesn't `seq.insert( newidx, seq.pop(oldidx) )` do this job in one line?

Comment: @TimRoberts No.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A linear time one. I start with a result list full of dummy objects. Then move elements from the input sequence into the result list as requested. Then replace the remaining dummies in the result with the remaining non-dummy elements from the input sequence.

```py
from typing import Any


def move_elements(
    seq: list[Any],
    new_idxs: dict,
) -> list[Any]:

    dummy = object()
    res = [dummy] * len(seq)
    seq = seq[:]

    for old, new in new_idxs.items():
        res[new] = seq[old]
        seq[old] = dummy

    remaining = (x for x in seq if x is not dummy)
    for i, x in enumerate(res):
        if x is dummy:
            res[i] = next(remaining)

    return res


def test(seq, new_idxs, expect):
    result = move_elements(seq, new_idxs)
    print('seq:     ', seq)
    print('new_idxs:', new_idxs)
    print('expect:  ', expect)
    print('result:  ', result)
    print('correct? ', result == expect)
    print()

test([0, 1], 
     {0: 1, 1: 0},
     [1, 0])
test([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
     {3: 0, 5: 1},
     [3, 5, 0, 1, 2, 4, 6, 7])
test([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
     {3: 6, 5: 7},
     [0, 1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 3, 5])
test([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
     {3: 1, 7: 4},
     [0, 3, 1, 2, 7, 4, 5, 6])
```

Output ([Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=lVPNjtMwED5wy1PMrQnyoi7tbpGlgniOKFotzWQxiu3gTCDViifhshd4EB6Dp2H8E7dFIEEOkTPffD8Z21-_D0d6b83T07eJuqtXP5_96JzVQMdBmQdQerCO4K05FkXRYgfafsI77FGjobEsgJ8RP0ro1Ug1tzUi1Ax-vlPtPEpo1YFEUcHV61OPLEJTO2l9hD3Ydx_wQGUVig5HLtUBa-A59GhKdqgWKwb5XcsmanTWge1b4R1BmWz8QhHqsaxk6ErCNaNNEmBSk7GlwFgwLlIUfa-MH8MeyjlYzd7Dp1CdX49gLEVKleMoEdvQTBrdPWHJ1mdBFmqgncpLRuVTGJypzP7VkocmZ3xT2gzCkfxwRP5tATgPPMxkx61TT6x3uW0XlBh8cMpQuQp76Z-VgDz1hOU9Xf2FHK1lIKcY53AME-G4voAP1jmmvDnBsN__QYeHEf67Xgu4bgTEAT6uJVxzQcL6SzyCUPP3uqnOugW8FLARsBVwI-BWwC4dV3jcMJGrLJLpm9CVedvE-HfB2yC4y4K_SwXqzX8IMryTsD0X3CykXSY1VbzK6UYvN_sX)):

```
seq:      [0, 1]
new_idxs: {0: 1, 1: 0}
expect:   [1, 0]
result:   [1, 0]
correct?  True

seq:      [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
new_idxs: {3: 0, 5: 1}
expect:   [3, 5, 0, 1, 2, 4, 6, 7]
result:   [3, 5, 0, 1, 2, 4, 6, 7]
correct?  True

seq:      [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
new_idxs: {3: 6, 5: 7}
expect:   [0, 1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 3, 5]
result:   [0, 1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 3, 5]
correct?  True

seq:      [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
new_idxs: {3: 1, 7: 4}
expect:   [0, 3, 1, 2, 7, 4, 5, 6]
result:   [0, 3, 1, 2, 7, 4, 5, 6]
correct?  True
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution:

```
def move_elements(
    seq: list,
    new_idxs: dict
) -> list:
    result = [None] * len(seq)
    for old, new in new_idxs.items():
        result[new] = seq[old]
    
    for val in seq:
        res_idx = 0
        while res_idx < len(seq) and result[res_idx] != None:
            res_idx += 1

        if res_idx == len(seq): return result
        
        if val in result: continue
        result[res_idx] = val
               
    return result
```

Output (for your test cases):

```
[1, 0]
[3, 5, 0, 1, 2, 4, 6, 7]
[0, 1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 3, 5]
[0, 3, 1, 2, 7, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: Fails if there are duplicates, for example `move_elements([3, 3], {})` returns `[3, None]`.